# How can I get UTXO for a specific address?

Tags: utxo

Are there API's I can use to get this information?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Electrum servers via [`blockchain.address.listunspent`](http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/protocol.html#blockchain-address-listunspent)

An example implentation: [[1]](https://github.com/shesek/bcash-instadump/blob/master/lib/utxo.js#L6) that calls [[2]](https://github.com/shesek/bcash-instadump/blob/f672bb035c9e8127ea407057da7d0cff4819cf0d/lib/electrum.js#L30) (Note: this is an altcoin implementation)